# Auto-complete for public GitHub repos?

Tags: library, javascript, api, git, github

I have an app which asks users for their GitHub repo name. For a better UX experience, I was wondering if there are any tools/extension so that when you start typing your public repo name it would give you a list of all the repos starting with that name so you can choose yours from the list? Like an auto-completion for public repos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to go this using their official v3 api and promises. You can find their API here: https://developer.github.com/v3/users about users and this one https://developer.github.com/v3/repos for the repositories. I hope this helps.

Comment: And where does that API cover what OP asked for? Or does it cover it at all?

Comment: It seems that it does cover the OP’s question.

Comment: Yes, OP accepted. But there are others coming here via search engines etc and might wish to know. Maybe you could [edit] your answer and elaborate a little more (see [our answer quality guide](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) for some background)?